# drag to show and hide content

Tags: jquery

How would I go about making a draggable drop down effect?

Where you have a visible handle at the top of the screen, you click and hold the handle and drag down to show it's content.  THen you can drag it back up again to hide the content.

So basically, I would like to have a div, with a handle, which I can click and hold to resize the div to show more content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Answer (score 0):

try the [jQuery UI Draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement). Constrain-movement is what you looking for.

Comment: It's more of a stretch effect I am after, i.e. have a handle for a div, then drag the handle to stretch the height of the div.