# Dragging up to hide a div like mobile, jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag

I have this section in my application which I wanted to hide upon drag up like those in mobile phones, is this possible using jquery? or maybe jquery ui?

here is the screenshot of what I did,

[image]

Comment: Is it possible using jQuery? Sure. Have you tried anything?

Comment: i tried using draggable by jquery-ui, but it only moves the element itself.

Comment: Please post your HTML/CSS and anything you've tried. Also it helps to post a jsFiddle link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433182/drag-to-show-and-hide-content looks like it might be what you're looking for.  It was the third entry down on google for "jquery drag up hide".